# matplotlib.plot doesn't show any image or plot without any error

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to show some images on VScode in Ubuntu, but matplotlib doesn't work. For example, even the most simple code such as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s_in =  plt.imread("/media/aro/New Volume/Super resolution dataset/set5/Test/BSDS100/3096.png")
plt.imshow(s_in)
plt.show()
```

is not working, and it doesn't show any errors or warnings. What should I do?

Comment: If you run `print(s_in)`, what do you get?

Comment: @swatchai I get the values of the whole matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody has got the same problem as mine. The error was because of the backend. So I had to change it. the only backend that worked for me was *WebAgg*.

Just add the following code at the beginning of your code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.switch_backend('WebAgg')
```